# Logout from Uber Ride Request widget

Tags: swift, logout, uber-api

I am using the Uber Ride Request Widget in my app.

Once the modal view controller appears, I am setting a logout button:

```
behavior!.modalRideRequestViewController.rideRequestViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = navigationBarLeftItem
```

I know that to logout I need to use these 2 lines of code:

```
TokenManager.fetchToken()
TokenManager.deleteToken()
```

What I am facing is that I need to refresh the uber page presented modally to redirect me to the login page of uber.

Is that possible? Or I need to switch to the "Implicit Grant" way for doing the whole login and logout process myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to get that behavior with the standard RideRequestViewController. If you log the user out, the next time you present the widget, it should go to the login screen.

I don't have a lot of context, but it sounds like you want to have the widget as a primary view controller of your app (rather than presenting it modally), in which case I would suggest using the stand alone RideRequestView in your own custom ViewController & using the LoginManager with the implicit grant flow as you mentioned

Also, you only need to call `TokenManager.deleteToken()` to delete the current access token.

`TokenManager.fetchToken()` just returns the current access token